# Electron issue with download attribute

Tags: javascript, html, download, electron

Following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826702/electron-page-is-refreshed-when-converting-html5-canvas-to-jpeg),

I have a **desktop application** using **Electron** platform and Javascript where I am converting an HTML5 canvas to JPEG using:

```
<a id="download" download="Path.jpg">Download JPG</a>
```

then,

```
function download(){ 
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    this.href=dt; 
}
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

This refreshes my whole application. How can I change this behavior, such that the page does not refresh when the download attribute is clicked?

Comment: Will this be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067298/saving-files-locally-with-electron

Comment: add `target="_blank"` in your anchor tag to stop the refresh

Comment: Hi @AshokVishwakarma, unfortunately this does not work for me . I still get the whole application refreshing.

Comment: @Rrz0, i think your code has some other issue which may be causing the refresh. Because your approach should work as it is in Chrome/Electron

Comment: @TarunLalwani, it could be but this is highly unlikely. I do not (think that I) have anything else which may cause this refresh. According to Kaiido, in an answer from my previous question, "The problem is with Electron's implementation of the download attribute", but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Can you create a minimal git repo with all packages you are using? So we can debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of this two snippets, one using blob and one using the download element. external-library: [FileSave.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
// this one use FileSaver.js library
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    saveAs(blob, "pretty image.png");
});

// or this way using download element.
// here you can encode your image-data and then send it.
var download = document.getElementById('download');
download.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(imageData));
download.setAttribute('download', 'file.jpg');
```

also I found this one just now, electron specific solution :
[Saving files locally with electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067298/saving-files-locally-with-electron?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I have tried the second code snippet followed by `document.getElementById...` and indeed it does not refresh. Upon pressing save, the application is not refreshed, but the image is not being saved!

Comment: sorry u mean nothing happened (nothing come up)? or the file was not the right format? what about the first one?  I'll check them now

Comment: Second snippet, did not refresh the application, but the image was not saved. Completely not saved, and not simply wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your anchor tag a bit

```
<a id="download" download="Path.jpg" target="_blank" onClick="download();">Download JPG</a>
```

And then your download function

```
function download(event){
    event.currentTarget.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
}
```

This might help

Comment: Thanks for the full answer. Will try this implementation too.

Comment: For some reason I am getting `download is not a function` when clearly I have a function named `download`.

Comment: Is your download function global?

Comment: An alternative is to add the same using `document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', download, false);` and remove onClick property on anchor tag

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole application is still refreshing with the above code implemented.